# Selecting an exact number of words in Word 2007

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

How would I go about having Word 2007 select an exact number of words from the cursor position? The count according to Non-Asian words would be particularly helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use VB to do this. Place the following code into the VB browser (<kbd>Ctl</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>). You can place it in the `NewMacros` folder and it will be available in all the new documents you create. Or you can place it in the `ThisDocument` for it to only be available in the document you are working with.

```
Sub SelectWords()
Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdWord, Count:=10, Extend:=wdExtend
End Sub
```

Adjust the `Count:=` number to be the number of words you want selected.

[image]

To run the macro, open the marco window with <kbd>Atl</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd> and run SelectWords.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. I ran the macro and it did what it was supposed to, but it seems this method will only work for files that have nothing but English in them. When I use files that have both Japanese and English in them, it counts the Japanese characters (in groups), as well as the tags used by the translation program. Sentences are formatted like this: {0>Japanese text<}0{>English text<0}. Obviously this could become overly complicated, so what about limiting the selected text to a certain font?

Comment: The code was written to just count words. Surely the extra characters are confusing how it counts, so I understand why it didn't work. From your question, I did not realize there were Japanese characters within the sentences. Sorry, I am not sure how to get it to only count words with a certain font type.

Comment: Can you post an example? Maybe there is a way to figure it out using the special characters.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about the lack of information in my original question. Here is a simple example: {0>第6章<}100{>Chapter 6<0} What should be a word count of 2 is 14. The tags are formatted as subscripts if that makes a difference. The reason I thought this would be possible (without writing hundreds of lines of code) is that the word count function in Word has a line for Non-Asian characters that always gives the correct count.